# From the Body or the Brain

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I come from your body, or from your brain

Use me a little to mask all your pain

Use me a lot, the world thinks you're insane

But I'm contagious, so don't break the chain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it be:

> laughter

I come from your body, or from your brain

> Laughing is a physical action - you can force a laugh, or it can come from your brain if you think something is funny

Use me a little to mask all your pain

> Uneasy laughter hides what you think or can distract you from your current (perhaps painful) situation

Use me a lot, the world thinks your insane

> The Joker (from Batman) laughs a lot and a lot of villains have like signature laughs. In a friend circle, the one who laughs a lot over everything can be seen as odd or weird. A lot of tv shows/movies portray insane people as laughing at whatever thoughts are inside their heads.

But I'm contagious, so don't break the chain

> Laughing can be contagious and sometimes people can think someone's laugh is funny and start laughing

Comment: Beat me by seconds :) Smiling also fits

Comment: You're quick!  Good job.

Comment: @Errorum welcome to puzzling! Nice first riddle, liked the rhymes. Was laughter or smiling the intended answer?

Comment: Laughter.  "From the body or the brain"  was a reference to the fact that it can be either a physical response to tickling, or a mental response to humor.  Smiling works for most (since smiling is requisite for laughter), but the world thinking you're insane for smiling is a bit of a stretch.

Answer (score 2):

Its

> Laughing/Smiling

I come from your body, or from your brain

> Your brain controls your facial expressions

Use me a little to mask all your pain

> Smiling or laughing an injury off

Use me a lot, the world thinks your insane

> Maniacal laughing or crazy smiling

But I'm contagious, so don't break the chain

> Laughing and smiling is contagious